# ESLint reports no-undef error on flow-typed global types

Tags: reactjs, eslint, flowtype, eslint-config-airbnb

I have global types defined in `/flow-typed/redux.flow.js` :

```
declare type Action = {|
  +type: string,
  +payload: any,
|}

declare type State = {|
  +ui: UI,
  +user: User,
  +team: Team,
  +projects: Project[],
  +profile: Profile,
|}

declare type UI = {|
  +isSliderOpen: boolean,
  +isModalVisible: boolean,
  +modalAction: string,
  +modalPayload: Object,
|}

...
```

I have added airbnb eslint configuration to my project and now I get:

```
type Props = {
  logout: () => Action, //error ESLint 'Action' is not defined.(no-undef)
  user: UserDetails, //error ESLint 'UserDetails' is not defined.(no-undef)
}
```

Its purelly eslint fault. Everything is configured properly and flow by itself is happy.

How to tell eslint that these types are indeed declared as global? or should I add them to some ignore list?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It turned out (like I thought) the way is not to add global types to eslint ignore list. Actually it's is all handled by [eslint-plugin-flowtype](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype) which I already had installed but I didn't extend it like:

**.eslintrc**

```
"extends": ["airbnb", "plugin:flowtype/recommended"],
"plugins": [
  "flowtype"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define global variables either using comments inside of a file, in the eslint configuration file or package.json. Read how to do it in [eslint docs](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals). If you need more help leave a comment.

Comment: Is this only solution? I would then have to have ignored every type from flow-typed directory like: `SyntheticInputEvent` or `Dispatch`